# Laravel 5.6 change QueuedCommand messages to something more readable

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5.6

So,

a I'm trying to use the Commands class for the first time, I want to make the queue messages more readable then `[2018-09-01 17:57:47][276] Processing: Illuminate\Foundation\Console\QueuedCommand`

So what I have done is the following;

I registered the Command `ConvertRecording` With `protected $signature = 'recording:convert {recording_id}';` and `protected $description = 'Convert a recording from mkv to mp4 using an recording id and making use of ffmpeg';`.This has an empty constructor, since I don't need to have an object passed to it... And the handle method just has some working code and some `$this->log()` commands...

Now, when I call the artisan command, I use the following code:

```
$exitCode = Artisan::queue('recording:convert', [
    'recording_id' => $recording_id
]);
```

And it appends to the queue, but I get only messages like thse:

```
[2018-09-01 17:57:47][276] Processing: Illuminate\Foundation\Console\QueuedCommand
[2018-09-01 17:58:16][276] Processed:  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\QueuedCommand
```

How could I change it to something like `[2018-09-01 17:58:16] Procesing: Video with ID [video ID here]`

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are looking to do something with Queued Commands that they are not really meant to do. What you are seeing in your logs is exactly what a Job is meant to do - that is, report when it is starting and when it has completed (or failed). It's the Command where the useful work is being done, and so all your output and logging should be done there.

Commands, naturally, have some console logging tools such as *error, info and comment* that can assist you in debugging:

```
$this->error('This is an error and will appear highlighted in the console');
$this->info('This is information');
$this->comment('This is a comment');
```

However, using these in a production environment may not work as your queue workers won't  a console to log to (I may be mistaken, as I have never tried to look).

I recommend simply setting up a dedicated log file for your commands using a ServiceProvider.

Comment: It would be great to have specific messages displayed in the queue, since I would like to give (in production) feedback via that console... but I'll have to dig deeper into that I think

Comment: I think that may not be possible, since your queues typically would run under a process that may not have console to log to. But I am not familiar enough with the workings of the OS to state that outright. If you want realtime output, then maybe the Broadcast functionality of Laravel would help here.